# How to get files and directories set up for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am doing prep work for App Academy but I am having a hard time setting up files/directories to be able to run everything correctly. I have a couple questions and haven't been able to find concrete answers:

1. How do you make a directory in the windows terminal?
2. How do you run files previously written in Notepad in IRB? I wrote some simple scripts in Notepad because Sublime was causing me severe migraines. Or how do you change Notepad files to Ruby files?
3. How do you create new files in IRB like `test_code.rb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) When at the Windows command prompt and having navigated to your working directory, type `md directory_name`

2) Unless you have specifically told notepad otherwise, notepad will have saved your file as a `.txt` file.  You will simply have to rename the file extension from `*.txt` to `*.rb`.

3) When you installed Ruby on your Windows machine, the Ruby interpreter would have undoubtably been added to your path, so you should just be able to run your `*.rb` file direct from the windows cmd prompt and it will execute.
**To *load* it while in IRB**: Make sure you run IRB from the same folder as your `*.rb` file is in.  Once you have cranked up an IRB session, type `load 'my_file.rb'`.

Answer (score 1):

IRB is a great environment for testing code, but not for writing full scripts. Use Notepad or Notepad++ or Vim for Windows or your editor of choice, as long as it's capable of generating a text (non word processing document).

You can make a directory in the terminal or in the Explorer, it doesn't matter. Just note where you created it so you don't lose it.

If you want to run a script in Ruby, simply type `ruby /path/to/the/file/script_to_run.rb` and the Ruby interpreter should load and run the file.

You *can* load a script into IRB and watch it run, but that's rarely something we need to do. More often you'll want to run scripts using Ruby, and try things in IRB, since it's like a scratchpad.